# Execute Subqueries of a View

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a rather large view constructed using the "WITH" statement. I've build the view's logic using small, understandable sub queries which are built on top of each other.

The result is a clearly structured SQL which (I believe ) is good to follow even if you're not the creator.

My problem comes with debugging in the future. If at some stage a collegue wants to understand how the result of the view is computed, it's a good approach to to execute some of the sub queries.

The usual approach would be to copy the view's SQL to an SQL-editor (e.g. SQL-Developer) and to replace the main statement with the subquery you're interested in.

Example:

```
WITH 
all_orders AS (
   SELECT order, price ... FROM ...
),

all_customers AS (
    SELECT id, 
           last_name, 
           first_name, 
           first_order_date ... 
    FROM...
),

new_customers AS (
    SELECT id, 
           last_name, 
           first_name 
    FROM all_customers
    WHERE first_order_date > ...
)

-- main SQL
SELECT ... FROM all_orders a
INNER JOIN new_customers ON (...)
```

If I have the feeling that something is wrong with "new_customers"  I would comment out the main SQL and replace it with:

```
...
-- main SQL
-- SELECT ... FROM all_orders a
-- INNER JOIN new_customers ON (...)

SELECT * FROM new_customers;
```

If I see that new_customers contains wrong data and I want to check if at least it's source "all_customers" is correct, I replace my main SQL again with

```
...
-- main SQL
-- SELECT ... FROM all_orders a
-- INNER JOIN new_customers ON (...)

SELECT * FROM all_customers;
```

That works really well but as soon as the SQL is inside a view I only have access to the result of the main SQL as the normal output of the view.

However, for simple debugging (meaning without going to the SQL editor, looking up the views definition and coping the SQL to the SQL editor) it would be really helpful to have some kind of database function where I could say:

```
SELECT * FROM RUN_SUBQUERY('my_view_name', 'new_customers');
```

**My question: Is there such a database function or some similar approach which would allow me to quickly execute sub queries of a database view without splitting the logic up into sub views?**

See below for my experience with sub views.

**Alternatives**

1. Split the big view in separate smaller views:

   - I tried this. The execution speed of the SQL dropped by factor 10. Since this is way too slow I'm also looking at some possible optimization here - however, I've seen it running really well when it was all in one statement/ view so it's hard to justify the extra effort here. Again, I only need the sub query results for debugging.
2. Keep the big view and additionally split it into smaller views which are just used for debugging:

   - This might be a way to go but we all know that having logic defined in two places is never a good idea (DRY).

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. You've stated a problem that doesn't really exist now, and that you have a workaround for if it does (getting the view source and running that); functionality that doesn't exist; and two approaches you've already rejected. What are you asking?

Comment: Hi Alex, I changed the article and hopefully stated the question clearer. thanks for your comment!

Comment: No, there isn't anything built-in to do that. You could potentially write your own function to parse the source text and try to extract a CTE, but it would be a lot of effort for not much real gain, in my opinion. The only reason I can think you'd even want to try is to keep the source hidden; but then anyone debugging would presumably have to see the bigger picture anyway, and would need to see the source to know what the CTE is called.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function that returns a table of records.
In this function you can according to the input parameters construct your sql differently and return the result with a cursor.

So for example:

```
select * from table(cast(run_subquery('my_view_name','new_customers' as a_table_of_records_type));
```

and this calls the function run_subquery:

```
function RUN_SUBQUERY (VNAME IN VARCHAR2,QNAME IN VARCHAR2)
return a_table_of_records_type is
    query_string varchar2(4000);
begin
  if VNAME = '...' then
    query_string := query_string || '....';
  end if;
  if VNAME = '...' then
    query_string := query_string || '....';
  end if;
  -- Execute string through refcursor and put the output in a_table_of_records_type
  return a_table_of_records_type;
end;
```

Comment: Do you mean to craft my own function? I like your approach since it shows that it is not too hard to accomplish.